# Trying to spoof MAC address. Is the old address still supposed to show when you opt+click the Wi-Fi icon in MacOS?

Tags: macos, wifi, mac-address

I'm using MacOS Big Sur and I wanted to spoof my MAC address through Terminal. After verifying my network interface to be en0:

I generated a random MAC address using

```
openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/./0/2; s/.$//'
```

and got:

```
60:ec:ed:24:be:57
```

Then I used

```
sudo ifconfig en0 ether 60:ec:ed:24:be:57
```

to change it to the new address, which prompted me to enter the root password, and I did. Lastly, to verify that it worked, I used

```
ifconfig en0 | grep ether
```

and it showed that it indeed changed to the new address:

```
    ether 60:ec:ed:24:be:57
```

However, when I option+click the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar at the top, it still shows my old MAC address. Does this mean it hasn't in fact changed?

For future reference, if I wanted to spoof my MAC address from my old one to a new one, would I have to disconnect from my network/disable Wi-Fi before and after entering the "sudo ifconfig en0 ether (new address)" command?

Edit: I also did all this while connected to NordVPN if that affects anything.

Comment: I'd be really good to have your question answered